# Grails - asynchronous communication with 3rd party API

Tags: java, grails, frameworks, concurrency, asynchronous

I'm experimenting with grails in order to interface with an online trading platform.
specifically Interactive Brokers (IB) http://interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=programInterface&ib_entity=llc

The way the API works is you need to have their client program, Trader Workstation (TWS http://interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=tws&ib_entity=llc) running and then we consume the API to do stuff. Consuming the API basically involves creating a "broker" object, calling a connect() member function (this makes a local port connection to the TWS software) and calling something like getData()

The value of grails in this scenario are the GORM features and the web framework provided. I want to be able to define objects abstracted from db implementation, easily do persistance operations and easily provide users with a UI to do CRUD and custom actions.

My challenge is the IB API uses asynchronous communication for requests and replies. i.e. when i call getData(), the API knows to use the callback function dataResults() when it is ready to send them.  In order for dataResults() to be callable, the broker object I created still needs to be around to receive the reply.
Inside a controller function, if i create a broker object and call getData(), when the request finishes, the broker object obviously also disappears. So I'll never be able to receive the reply.

I think there might be some way to do this by kicking off background threads but i'm not sure this is the path i want to go down.

Does anyone have any recommendations on what the best approach is?
I'm not married to grails, the reasons i'm using it are above. If there is a desktop app framework that I can also easily make a web interface on top of later, I'm definitely open to that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your object in Service and [make the Service singleton](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/services.html#scopedServices) (which is by default):

```
static scope = "singleton"
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of web UI Grails is definitely a good choice.
Then, the asynchronous operations could be handled by Ajax calls as you shouldn't block the controller waiting for results.
The following [presentation][1] has some good examples

1: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/java-jee/high-volume-scalable-ajax-with-grails

Comment: It's not about async browser-to-grails-server, it's about async server-to-third-party communication.

Comment: Yes. I get that, but this forces the async model all the way through as blocking the controller is rarely a good idea IMHO.

Comment: Slow async 3rd party doesn't necessarily make controller synchronous. I believe, opposite is true: async API itself forces UI design to account for async operations.