# Architecture for highly asynchronous events that result in database updates

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, actor, gpars

I originally asked [Handling database-backed async callbacks in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617336/handling-database-backed-async-callbacks-in-grails), but I've done a lot of research since then, so I am asking a more pointed question...

Most recently, I tried using the Events API in the platform-core plugin, but the optimistic and pessimistic locks and session and transaction management, combined with the nondeterministic callbacks, have make this impossible to get solid and stable.  I'm still chasing my tail.

So, I'm considering a different approach, but I am not experienced enough with GPars and Actors to know if I'm approaching this correctly.  What I'm thinking of doing is creating a single Actor that is responsible for ALL database updates.  The only way that anything gets written to the database is by sending a message to this singleton Actor.  All the asynchronous callbacks will do their logic, but anything that involves a database write will be sent to the DatabaseActor.

Is that a crazy bottleneck?  Is it a reasonable architecture?

Comment: If I were on your position, I will create my own stack from scratch.  I won't even consider hibernate or JPA.  something very thin and light, and very close to bare metal.  You will have lots of business logic about this.  Like tons of validations and business logic to make sure the orders are valid/make sense. (e.g. checking for cross order, etc)

Comment: You make a good point... although I hate it.  :-)  I do not want to start over at this point.  Even if I incur the technical debt for now, I'd like to resolve this, at least temporarily, in a less drastic way than a rewrite.  Any thoughts on using an Actor as described?